# class and private members

Tags: java, class, private

```
class MC {

    private String name;

    void methodA(MC mc){
        System.out.println(mc.name);
    }

}
```

Why am I able to access name variable in `methodA`? I am confused here, can someone please explain?

Comment: I suggest reading: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tip-mem-visibility.html.

Answer (score 6):

You can access it because `methodA` is part of class `MC`.  Every method in a class can access that class's private data members (in the current instance and in any other instance).  Only other classes cannot.  For example:

```
class MC {
    private String name;

    void methodA(MC mc){
        System.out.println(mc.name);
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    void printMC(MC mc){
        System.out.println(mc.name);  //compiler error here
    }
}
```

Here is some official documentation on this topic:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 3):

Because `private` does not apply to the *object*, it applies to the *class*. If `private` applied to the *object*, then your intuition would be correct: `MC.methodA` would have access to `this.name`, but it would **not** have access to `mc.name` (where `mc` is some other `MC` object).

However, a subtle rule of visibility modifiers is that they control access for any code *in that class* to the members of *the other objects of that same class*. So all of the code in the `MC` class has access to the private `name` field of all objects of type `MC`. That is why `MC.methodA` has access to `mc.name` (the name of some other `MC` object) and not just its own name.

**Edit**: The relevant section of the Java Language Specification is [6.6.1 Determining Accessibility](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.1):

> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared `private`, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class ([§7.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#26783)) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Answer (score 2):

because you have accessed it from the scope it's private to.

your private implementations and data will be private to (and accessible in) the scope (e.g. class) they have been declared in.

Comment: I suspect the question is, why does "private" not restrict you to accessing the field only in `this`?

Comment: I don't think "scope" is the best concept to use to explain this.  It's really better explained using "visibility", as in the [official documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).